Using React to dynamically generate checkboxes, but unable to change their state
I used useEffect to fetch an API and dynamically generate several checkboxes. I used onChange to change their state in an array. However, when I click on a checkbox, it does not change its checked or unchecked state. I need to click another static checkbox first to make the previous checkbox change its state. Here is my code.
<div className="fullinput list_checkbox_inline">
<SubmitOrg
localCheckBoxChange={handleorg}
editMod={editMod}
ref={submitOrgRef }
/>
</div>

import React, { Component, useEffect, useState, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';
const SubmitOrg = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const [OrgList, setOrgList] = useState();
    const [checkState, setCheckState] = useState(false);
    const [movieOrg, setMovieOrg] = useState([]);

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        setChildInitValData() {
            InitValData()
        }
    }))

    async function InitValData() {
        if (props.editMod != null) {
            let myarray = OrgList;

            let refarray = props.editMod.tbl_image_movie_contentinvolveorg
            if (refarray != null) {
             
                for (let i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
                    let localkid = myarray[i].cbval;
                    let y = refarray.filter(element => element.imc_orgcd === localkid);
                  
                    if (y.length > 0)
                        myarray[i].ischecked = "checked"

                }
                setOrgList(myarray)
            }
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        GetOrgList();
    }, []);
    async function GetOrgList() {
        const response = await fetch('/api/GetOrgCode/GetOrgDataCheckBox');
        const data = await response.json();
       
        setOrgList(data);
        props.localCheckBoxChange(data)
    }

  async   function CheckBoxChange(e) {
        var mycheckval = e.target.getAttribute('val')
        var myischecked = e.target.checked
        let operkey = e.target.getAttribute('data-id')
        let myarray = OrgList;
        for (let i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
            let localkid = myarray[i].cbval;
            if (localkid == operkey) {
                if (myischecked)
                    myarray[i].ischecked = "checked"
                else
                    myarray[i].ischecked = ""
            }
        }
        

        props.localCheckBoxChange(myarray)
         setOrgList(myarray)
         //document.getElementById("chk_org_99").click();
    }

    const handleSelectChange = (event) => {
        const value = event.target.value;
        const checked = event.target.checked;
        setCheckState(checked)    
    };

    const CateContents = OrgList === undefined ?
        <><p>Loading...</p>

        </>
        :
        <>
            <div className="fullinput list_checkbox_inline">

                <input data-id="99" id="chk_org_99" type="checkbox" name="chk_org_99" onChange={(event) => handleSelectChange(event)} checked={checkState} />
                <label for="chk_org_99">test</label>
            </div>
                {OrgList.map(items =>
                    <>
             
                        <input data-id={items.cbval} key={items.cbval} id={'chk_org_' + items.cbval} type="checkbox" name={'chk_org_' + items.cbval} val={items.cbval} onChange={CheckBoxChange} checked={items.ischecked==='checked'} />
                        <label key={'lbl_org_' + items.cbval} htmlFor={'chk_org_' + items.cbval}>{items.cbval}</label> 
                    </>

                )}
            </>
    return (<>{CateContents}</>)
})
export{ SubmitOrg };

I need to click another static checkbox first to make the previous checkbox change

I believe each item to have it's own independent checkbox right?
